# How to log Windows processes?

Tags: windows, process, logging

Although I tried various templates with Perfmon,procmon and 3rd party applications, I could not find an application that did exactly what I wanted.

What need

- Logging Process name
- CPU usage
- CPU time
- Memory (Private working set)
- Threads
- Command Line information

of existing or to be added new processes. This information can actually be seen in the task manager, but I want to log in the background and send mail if possible. Or is there a method to log the task manager?

Comment: You are going to need monitoring software for this. to my knowledge these packages are all paid and very expensive.

Comment: typeperf is pretty close.

Comment: did you do any research yourself yet?

Comment: To get the missing data, maybe the export and sending of email and if Command Line Information is important, I'd probably look at PowerShell, see Get-Counter.

Comment: After 6 months of research I decided to ask here. We also tried paid and complex software such as Solarwinds, PRTG. @Albin

Comment: The closest application to this was Sysgauge, but their report section does not work either.

Comment: @drnlcrgy sorry, the question didn't imply 6 months of research ;) It would be helpfull I you would share your experience so far.